# Hitting time $h_i(k)\geqslant h_i(j)\cdot h_j(k)$

Tags: markov-chains

> > Let $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}$ be a Markov chain with state space $E$. The *hitting time* of a set $A\subseteq E$ is a RV
> >     $$
> > H(A)\colon\Omega\to\mathbb{N}_0\cup\left\{\infty\right\},~~\omega\mapsto\inf\left\{n\in\mathbb{N}_0 | X_n(\omega)\in A\right\}.
> > $$
> >     The probability starting from $i\in E$ that $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}$ ever hits $A$  is
> >     $$
> > h_i(A):=\mathbb{P}_i(H(A)<\infty).
> > $$
> >     For $i,j\in E$ we write $h_i(j):=h_i(\left\{j\right\})$.
> >     Prove, for all $i,j,k\in E$ that
> >     $$
> > h_i(k)\geqslant h_i(j)\cdot h_j(k).
> > $$

I tried to prove that using
$$
\begin{cases}h_i(A)=1, & i\in A\\h_i(A)=\sum_{j\in E}p_{ij}h_j(A), & i\notin A\end{cases}
$$

Although I do not know if I can use that here and how to continue I at least have
$$
h_i(k)=\sum_{s\in E}p_{is}h_s(k)
$$
and
$$
h_i(j)\cdot h_j(k)=\sum_{s\in E}\sum_{t\in E}p_{is}h_s(j)p_{jt}h_t(k)
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This follows from the (strong) Markov property of the Markov chain at the first hitting time of $j$.

Note that $h_i(k)\geqslant P_i(B)$, where $B$ denotes the event that the Markov chain hits $j$ and that, after it hits $j$, it hits $k$. Conditionally on the path of the Markov chain up to the hitting time $\tau$ of $j$, the probability to hit $k$ after $\tau$ is the probability that the Markov chain hits $k$ starting from $j$, that is, $h_j(k)$. Thus, $P_i(B)=h_i(j)\cdot h_j(k)$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18217/discussion-on-answer-by-did-hitting-time-h-ik-geqslant-h-ij-cdot-h-jk).

Comment: Ok, but please tell me if my edited proof (below in my answer) is okay now. Then I will definitely stop discussing here.